# Angular 8 Reactive Form, Set Default Selected Option

Tags: angular-material, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

Sorry am struggling to set default selected option in drop-down list when I open Dialog Model Form.

I have two model

1. department
2. employee

Also i have two component which is employee and employee-list, employee-list component is responsible for load all list of employee in a table and employee component is responsible to load singe employee..

In employee-list i set click event which call edit function and populate selected row in a form for editing purpose.. but when form opne it open with other filed by select option does not appear i do not know why.

employee.ts

```
  dept: any;

     ngOnInit() {
      this.loadAllDept();
      this.selected = this.employeeService.form.get('department').value;
      }

    loadAllDept(){
        this.employeeService.getAllDepartments().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.dept = data;
          }
        );
      }
```

And my employee.html

```
    <mat-grid-tile>
      <div class="reg-control-container">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select [(value)]="selected"  formControlName="depatment" placeholder="Class">
            <mat-option>None</mat-option>
            <ng-container>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let d of dept" value="{{d.id}}"> {{ d.name }}</mat-option>
            </ng-container>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
```

but it does not set default value to a drop-down list.

Like the following picture show I can output both default selected and list of option but i can not set it.

[as shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72RTP.png)

Comment: Use property binding, like => `<mat-option  [value]=" yourValue ">`, then in the components code, you can initialize the control with the same value

Comment: I tried but still it does not work..

Comment: Maybe I'm not following your issue correctly, if you can be more specific as to what the issue is, I could help you better

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5short

Keep in mind that you need to bind the value of the option using the property binding syntax Angular provides, encasing the property you want to assign the value to in square brackets (`[]`). With that, as long as you pass the same value to the FormControl you want, it should apply the default option correctly.

Comment: I followed all procedure but still no luck.. Am able to console the default value to a browser but i can not set it as default value

Comment: I'm not following, it is not clear what you have tried, please provide more context

Comment: i added a picture to explain in detail

Comment: Okay, but how are you obtaining the `selected` object? If you are getting that, you can definitely assign that to the control